# Java: Picking a selection from a list

Tags: java, list, selection

I am writing my own Java board game, and I am not sure what to do with the following problem:

We have a list of numbers (a), lets say:
a = 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4

Now I need to pick a selection of x numbers from this list.
The selected numbers must exceed a predefined number when added up. The order of numbers does not matter.

The Problem: How do I get all possible selections without duplicates in an efficient way?

So for example:
from list a we need a selection of 3 numbers which exceed 4 when added up.
options are:
1,1,2
(1,2,1 is considered a duplicate, just as 2,1,1)
1,1,3
1,1,4
1,2,2
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,3,3
1,3,4
1,4,4
2,2,2
etc.

Comment: There's more possibilities than that. 4 + any two of the other numbers exceed 4; obviously.

Comment: Sorry, confused "exceeds" with "equals" myself. edited.

Comment: So this is actually a pretty hard problem.  Look at this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12262/create-a-list-of-all-possible-combinations-of-elements-into-n-groups-from-a-set .  Grab all of the possible combinations then add each number combination up and check if its greater then your number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enumerate all possible combinations of 3 numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] numbers = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4};
  int size      = 3;
  int minSum    = 4;

  search(numbers, size, minSum, 0, new LinkedList<Integer>());
}

private static void search(int[] numbers, int size, int minSum, int pos, Stack<Integer> stack) {
  if (stack.size() == size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int number : stack) {
      sum += number;
    }

    if (sum >= minSum) {
      System.out.println("Selection: " + stack);
    }

    return;
  }

  if (pos < numbers.length) {
    // Search by not adding the current number
    search(numbers, size, minSum, pos + 1, stack);
    // Search by adding the current number
    stack.push(numbers[pos]);
    search(numbers, size, minSum, pos + 1, stack);
    stack.pop();
  }
}
```

The algorithm can be made faster based on the fact that it currently treats the numbers in the array distinctly. That is, it treats the first "1" with the second "1" as distinct numbers. I will leave this for you to solve.

Comment: When I compile and run this, I get an error. Can't convert LinkedList to Stack! 
And when I change Stack to LinkedList in line 9, I get no output and when changing LinkedList to Stack in line 6, I get duplicate output (a loop)!

Comment: Ooops, replace LinkedList with Stack.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems to work fine, I will check this code out later when on my own pc.